# How to store/print an element of an array?

Tags: java, arraylist, int, element

I am writing java code to store and print numbers that are separated by white space in a single line code. I figured out how to separate them and store them in an arraylist. However I can't seem to figure how to store or print a single element of an array. I tried using the indexOf method however this isn't working so far for me.

any help would be appreciated!!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class r
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     String sampleString = in.nextLine();
     String[] stringArrays = sampleString.split("\\s+");

     int[] intArray = new int[stringArrays.length];
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<stringArrays.length;i++)
     {
         String numberAsString = stringArrays[i];
         intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
     }
     System.out.print(intArray.indexOf(1));

}
```

Comment: Replace all lines after `String[] stringArrays = sampleString.split("\\s+");` with `for(String s: stringArrays) {System.out.println(s);}`

Comment: but what if I want to print a specific element?

Comment: **but what if I want to print a specific element?** - Access it with its index. You do not need a loop for that e.g. write `System.out.println(stringArrays[0]);`  if you want to access the first element. Learn the basics of Java array from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

indexOf is a string method and can be used to get the position of characters in strings, this has nothig to do with arrays. The correct syntax you would use for accessing certain objects in an array is the bracket method. For example you have an array of ten ints named example.

```
int[] example = new int[10];
```

You would access the ints inside the array by pointing to the wanted index. To get the first element, you would have to call

```
example[0]
```

and so on for each element in the array. Remember that arrays are zero-indexed

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use java 8 API: stream(), map(), collect()

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> myList = Arrays.stream(args)
                .map(Integer::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        printAll(myList);
        printSpecificElement(myList, myList.indexOf(5));
    }

    static void printAll(List<Integer> arr) {
         Arrays.asList(arr)
            .stream()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

   static void printSpecificElement(List<Integer> arr, int index) {
        System.out.println(arr.get(index));
    }
}
```